# CRM Bitrix24 и @вторекретарь от МТС

Tags: битрикс24, crm, телефония

Инструкцию перечитал. Поддержка обеих систем говорит, что у нас всё корректно.
Проблема следующая:

Когда в автосекретарь поступает звонок, должно воспроизводиться голосовое меню. И оно действительно работает.
НО! Когда в Битрикс24 я задаю пользователям номера телефонов, звонок идёт прямо на номер пользователя, по приоритету, минуя голосовое меню.

Второй день бьюсь.

UPD: При отключении голосового меню в автосекретаре, лиды фиксируются, но звонки поступают по приоритету. А мне необходимо, чтобы звонящий выбирал специалиста.